# Replacement for Calcium Propionate for bread

Tags: substitutions, bread, food-preservation, additives

Hi we run a bakery and we understood that Calcium Propionate is not safe for regular consumption. Can some one suggest a safe preservative..

Comment: I would be helpful to clarify where you read that it i unsafe. US FDA for example regards this is safe.

Answer (score 1):

There do not appear to be established replacements however "micro-encapsulated sorbic acid" is advertised as inhibiting mold without destroying yeast. http://www.bakeryandsnacks.com/Product-innovations/Microencapsulated-Sorbic-Acid-The-Winning-Formula

Outside of the usual Internet echo-chamber of scary-ingredient phobia, there is no evidence or concern for Calcium Propionate (which is naturally occurring anyway.)

One study that seems to be cited exclusively is a tiny study published in the Journal of Pediatrics and Child Health from New Zealand. However, this study is pretty poor as far as they go. Only 27 children, methodology not shared, etc. It's important to point out that this seems to be the only study of its kind. It did not compel further study or elicit real concern from the medical/laboratory community. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1440-1754.2003.00222.x/fullIt

With all of that said, mold is usually not a concern with fresh baked or par-baked frozen dough as these breads go hard and stale before mold appears.